Error extending AppCompatEditText: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied
I'm trying to create a custom EditText through AppCompatEditText using the following:
class MyField(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.editTextStyle,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null, 0, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, R.attr.editTextStyle, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0)

}

That gives me this error:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor AppCompatEditText(p0: Context) defined in androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
public constructor AppCompatEditText(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?) defined in androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
public constructor AppCompatEditText(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?, p2: Int) defined in androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

Hovering over AppCompatEditText, which has the red line under it, gives me the same message -- but instead of highlighting any potentially missing arguments, the closing paren of each one is highlighted in red. Not sure if this is just a visual error or related to my problem.

I have a constructor overload defined for each one within the AppCompatEditText definition -- what am I missing that could be causing this?
I tried defining blocks after each constructor, defining arguments as nullable, and ensuring each overload has a specific value defined when it's called -- all result in the same error.

The compat version of EditText has no constructors with 4 arguments. You can pass only context, attributes set and default style.
Also, instead of manual constructors declaration, you can use simple statement with JvmOverloads annotation:
class MyField @JvmOverloads(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.editTextStyle,
) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
}

